# bash output redirect prob

Tags: bash, output-redirect

I want to count the number of lines output from a command in a bash script. i.e.

`COUNT=ls | wc -l`

But I also want the script to output the original output from `ls`. How to get this done? (My actual command is not `ls` and it has side effects. So I can't run it twice.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tee(1)` utility may be helpful:

```
$ ls | tee /dev/tty | wc -l
CHANGES
qpi.doc
qpi.lib
qpi.s
4
```

`info coreutils "tee invocation"` includes this following example, which might be more instructive of `tee(1)`'s power:

```
 wget -O - http://example.com/dvd.iso \
   | tee >(sha1sum > dvd.sha1) \
         >(md5sum > dvd.md5) \
   > dvd.iso
```

That downloads the file once, sends output through two child processes (as started via `bash(1)` process substitution) and also `tee(1)`'s stdout, which is redirected to a file.

Comment: Here's a variant to put the line count in a variable, rather than adding it to the output: `COUNT=$(ls -l | tee /dev/tty | wc -l)`

Comment: @Gordon Davisson, thanks, that would be more useful for what @nakiya wanted. :)

Comment: Technically, that's Bash's process substitution.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls | tee tmpfile | first command
cat tmpfile | second command
```

Answer (score 0):

Tee is a good way to do that, but you can make something simpler:

```
ls > __tmpfile

cat __tmpfile | wc -l
cat __tmpfile

rm __tmpfile
```